# Pourquoi vingt-deux?

Tags: nombres, argot

L'expression *vingt-deux* est souvent utilisée familièrement pour signaler l'approche d'un personnage auquel on veut cacher quelque chose :

> *Attention ! Vingt-deux ! dit Samson, l'aide saucier. Signalé par le chiffre d'alarme, M. Ouvrard le patron parut.* (Pierre Hamp, *Marée fraîche*, 1908, p. 68)
>   *Vingt-deux, v'là les flics.*

Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vingt) ne donne pas l'origine. Il s'agit certainement d'un code argotique. Sait-on lequel ? Ce code comportait-il d'autres nombres aujourd'hui oubliés ?

Comment: [Parce que « 1225874963863665966 v'la les flics » c'était un peu trop long !!!](http://www.qalc.fr/question/Pourquoi-dit-on-les-flics-4181)

Answer (score 14):

[Wikipédia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/22,_v%27l%C3%A0_les_flics_!) donne une série d'origines possibles, mais les considère toutes comme des théories, sans pouvoir attester de la véracité d'aucune. Pour moi, la plus plausible est :

> 22 serait une déformation du juron « Vain dieu ». Donc en gros, on dirait plutôt « Vain dieu, v'là les flics ! »

Mais elle est également [contestée](http://www.mon-expression.info/vingt-deux) et l'explication la plus communément acceptée semble être celle des linotypistes, déjà mentionnée dans un dictionnaire d'argot de 1894 :

> Quand le compagnon placé le plus près de la porte voit entrer le prote [=chef d'atelier] dans l’atelier de composition, il crie: « vingt-deux ! » synonyme d’attention. Quand c’est le patron, il crie « Quarante-quatre ! » En raison de l’importance du « singe », le chiffre est doublé (Argot d’imprimerie).

D'autres explications reposant sur la valeur numérique de 22 (2 fois 11, par exemple) me paraissent par contre nettement moins crédibles.

Comment: Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue Française* signale l'apparition du poignard avec une lame de 22 cm employé par les truands en 1837. *Vingt-deux v'la les flics* apparaissant en 1887, le glissement *sortez vos couteaux* −> *attention* semble plausible.

Comment: Mais je penche aussi  pour l'argot des linotypistes avec deux origines possibles :

- soit la taille des caractères, (explication donnée par Claude Duneton) :  la taille des caractères (dit le corps dans le jargon de l’imprimerie), pour former un texte, est habituellement de 9 ou 10. De ce fait le corps 22, destiné aux titres car de taille très importante, est tout désigné pour annoncer la venue du chef de manière anodine.

- soit le fait que vingt-deux est le transcodage du mot “CHEF” selon les numéros des lettres de l’alphabet :   3 + 8 + 5 + 6 = 22.

Comment: Références : http://www.mon-expression.info/vingt-deux

Answer (score 3):

Décomposons le mot Chef en 4 nombres :
**C = 3

H = 8

E = 5

F = 6**

Additionnez ces 4 nombres, et vous obtiendrez **22**.

Conclusion : **22** est une appellation chiffrée du mot "**Chef**".
note : l'appellation est uniquement utilisée dans le sens de personne de hiérarchie supérieure, et non de cuisinier.

Comment: Une source ? Cette explication a l'air un peu tirée par les cheveux, et pas facilement vérifiable

Comment: Mis à part le fait que je tenais cela du bouche à oreille de mes grands parents (ce qui n'est pas une source du tout, bien entendu), l'[article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/22,_v%27l%C3%A0_les_flics_!) cité par les autres réponses liste aussi cette théorie.

Answer (score 2):

La réponse semble avoir été posée par [@Laure](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/pourquoi-vingt-deux/1395#comment2740_1395). L'article de [wikipedia: 22, v'là les flics !](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/22,_v%27l%C3%A0_les_flics_!) la première proposition fait référence à *la longueur usuelle de la lame du couteau d'arsouille*.

L'expression signifierait:

> A vos armes!

#### Spéculations:

J'ai lu cet article il y a quelque mois, alors que je cherchais à comprendre le sens de l'expression *se faire arsouiller*. Ai tenté de glâner des infos supplémentaires, mais n'ai rien trouvé infirmant ou confirmant cette thèse.

Je choisis à titre personnel et de manière totalement arbitraire cette première proposition que **me** semble la plus cohérente.

Spéculations, toujours...

L'alléguation concernant les imprimeurs ressemble à un *hoax* (intox), une sorte de **très** vieille boutade de professionnels *taille 22 pour le chef*, mais *44 pour le patron*! (Une blague aussi peut *vivre* plus d'un siècle). Je n'ai pas trouvé de référence à ce propos aussi anciennes que concernant le couteau d'arsouille, mais peut-être ais-je insuffisament cherché...

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi, le « 22 » des linotypistes est de très loin l'explication la plus probable. Les corporations de l'époque avaient des argots propres qui ont influencé fortement les expressions de la langue commune. Un exemple très parlant est le *louchébem*, l'argot des bouchers, dont l'influence sur l'argot des « apaches » est très largement établie.
Il est assez illusoire de penser que les arsouilles parisiens, pauvres et illettrés, se soient préoccupés de la longueur précise, en centimètres, de leur couteaux.

De plus, le couteau n'a jamais été une arme très efficace en combat de rue, et particulièrement pas dans une bataille rangée entre par exemple les forces de l'ordre et une bande, ou entre bandes. Le bâton (plus tard le manche de pioche, à cause de sa disponibilité) est bien plus efficace et meurtrier.

Le couteau est à l'époque l'arme de proximité facilement dissimulable pour frapper une cible à l'improviste dans une foule, et certainement pas une arme de bataille. Pour rappel, jusque récemment les citoyens de bonne famille ne quittaient pas leur domicile sans une cane ferrée, en partie pour l'esbrouffe mais surtout pour l'autodéfense. Je parle ici du début-milieu du 20e siècle, pas du temps des dinosaures.

Les explications impliquant « dieu » (Vain dieu, vingt dieux, etc.) sont à mon sens totalement anachroniques, la langue populaire les ayant à ce moment abandonnées depuis longtemps -au moins plusieurs décades- sous les pressions combinées de l’église et de l’État.

L'explication la plus probable à mon sens est donc que l'expression « 22 », utilisée par la corporation des linotypistes pour signifier secrètement « attention » a été reprise par d'autres à cause de sa brièveté et de sa facilité d'utilisation.

Comment: Bienvenue sur *French Language*. Ceci n'est pas une réponse à la question posée mais une discussion sur les autres réponses déjà données.   *French Language* n'est pas un forum de discussion mais un site de questions réponses sur la langue française.